# Replacing standard library functions with custom higher order functions for unit testing

Tags: go

I'm working on increasing unit test coverage for my repository, covering to maximum extent possible. I have a particular routine in the package, that makes `ssh` and `sftp` connections. I'm trying to replace them with higher order functions (see [Higher-order functions in Go](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2023/higher-order-functions-in-go/) for reference) for the purposes of unit testing.

One such example set I have is below

```golang
type (
    // ssh.Dial prototype
    sshDialer     func(string, string, *ssh.ClientConfig) (*ssh.Client, error)
    // sftp.NewClient prototype
    sftpNewClient func(conn *ssh.Client, opts ...sftp.ClientOption) (*sftp.Client, error)
)
```

which I'm trying to convert to

```golang
type (
    // ssh.Dial prototype - Updated
    sshDialer     func(string, string, *ssh.ClientConfig) (SSHConnector, error)
    // sftp.NewClient prototype - updated
    sftpNewClient func(conn *ssh.Client, opts ...sftp.ClientOption) (SFTPConnector, error)
)
```

where `SSHConnector` and `SFTPConnector` are the custom interfaces satisfied by the native types respectively (see below playground link for full code)

Here is a full example (reproducible) of the code I’m dealing with in a Go snippet - https://go.dev/play/p/DZ3H9FRlbGI

The problem is I'm not able to make `ssh.Dial()` or `sftp.NewClient()` accept interface as their first arguments.

Seeing errors as below, which is meaningful, but just interested in finding a way to make it work

```
./prog.go:48:18: cannot use ssh.Dial (value of type func(network string, addr string, config *ssh.ClientConfig) (*ssh.Client, error)) as sshDialer value in struct literal
./prog.go:49:18: cannot use sftp.NewClient (value of type func(conn *ssh.Client, opts ...sftp.ClientOption) (*sftp.Client, error)) as sftpNewClient value in struct literal
```

I'm seeing errors as follows, which makes sense, but just interested in finding a way for it to work

I know mocking/patching methods are not recommended in Go’s overall testing strategy, but would like to make this from a learning/practice experiment.

Basically I’m trying to modify the prototype of `sshDialer` and `sftpNewClient`, to return an interface as the first return value, so that I can create a mock struct (using `gomock` or `testify/mock`) to further test my code. Is that achievable. Also would appreciate other approaches based on my code structure.

Comment: You should wrap the functions, not the types. The types need wrapping only if you need them to satisfy an unsupported interface, or modify their behaviour, otherwise they implicitly implement the interface, so wrapping them adds no benefit.

Comment: But, actually, since `sftpNewClient` is tightly coupled to the output of `sshDialer` you can utilize "type wrapping" by adding the "new sftp client" to the `sshWrapper` type, that way you'll be able to decouple from the concrete dependency completely.

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/B2xO0wgy4x1

Comment: @mkopriva Simple follow-up question from your earlier suggestion. I managed to test out my whole of SFTP/FTP clients with your idea. I have a rough outline of how I managed to achieve it - https://go.dev/play/p/tH_Ym-KgRFF But running golangci-lint on it I see `infinite recursive call (staticcheck)` errors on the Close() calls of sshWrapper, sftpWrapper and few other instances. They should be false positives right?

Comment: Those are likely true positives. The wrapper's methods should call the embedded field's methods through that embedded field. https://go.dev/play/p/nQk4mCgUptA